# What is the best iphone wireframe creator software? prototype

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

Can somebody tell me the best iPhone wireframe creator software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try iPlotz. Look for other tools [here](http://iphoneized.com/2009/11/21-prototyping-mockup-wireframing-tools-iphone-app-development/)

Comment: Its not a question for SO. Next time please post such questions on relevant stackexchange site. Stack Overflow [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 2):

You could try

It does sketchy wireframes and High Res ones depending on what you’re after and can turn them into an interactive prototype too. It will also export the coordinates of all the screen elements to a Word doc

[UxToolbox](http://www.softandgui.co.uk/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great free to to prototype iphone apps http://www.justinmind.com/prototyper/free-edition it's completely free and great to build clickable mockups for web and mobile apps. It has a good collaboration feature as well.